# Is there a way to use high-end gpus (like NVIDIA Titan xp or GTX 1080 Ti) for an embedded system?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-settings

I am trying to use high-performance GPUs like Titan or GTX series for an embedded system (to install in a vehicle). I already have Jetson tx2, but I need something more powerful. Is there a way to do this?

(I was told that I cannot use NVIDIA GPUs with TX2 because the drivers for these GPUs do not support ARM)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, there are a plethora of issues you will likely run into when trying to run a graphics card on an embedded system, most (if not all) embedded system provide no options for upgrades (as they are usually meant for small workloads), however if the system you are trying to install the GPU in has an adequate PCI bus and adequate power delivery for the GPU you could install the GPU. However even if you install a high-end GPU on an embedded system it will more than likely be heavily bottlenecked by the lack of CPU power and RAM. In short even if you could you probably wouldn't want to. If you wanted a high-end system in a vehicle you would probably be better off with a Mini PC.
Apologies if his answer is terrible I'm new here.